# How do I apply a style to all buttons of an ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net, css

Somebody asked similar question not long ago. But nobody answered comprehensively.

Assume I have:

```
<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="b2" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

I want to set the following property to both buttons:

```
height: 100px;
width: 50px;
```

Let's say both properties are included in a class. How do I apply that class into both buttons?

Thank's

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Method 1

Add a CSS stylesheet with the following [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

```
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

### Method 2

Use an [ASP.Net Theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx).

### Method 3

Set a class name on each button using the `CssClass` property.

Markup:

```
<asp:Button id="btn1" Text="Submit" CssClass="buttonStyle1" />
<asp:Button id="btn2" Text="Submit" CssClass="buttonStyle1" />
<asp:Button id="btn3" Text="Submit" CssClass="buttonStyle1" />
<!-- the class can be applied to any number of other elements -->
```

CSS:

```
.buttonStyle1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Btw, if I want to apply multiple classes. How should I do it?

Comment: @rofansmanao - you can apply multiple classes by separating them with spaces, like `CssClass="class1 class2 class3"`

Answer (score 3):

just give them the same class for css

```
 <asp:Button id="b1" CssClass="TestStyle" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button id="b2" CssClass="TestStyle" Text="Submit" runat="server" />

    .TestStyle
    {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    }
```